# Porting old CodeWarrior Project to Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, codewarrior

I have a very old command line utility in need of updating. Its project file is a CodeWarrior `.mcp`. Xcode used to be able to import CodeWarrior projects but that ability seems to have been removed in more recent versions.

What is the best way to import old CodeWarrior projects in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when Xcode quit supporting CodeWarrior imports, but CodeWarrior quit shipping for the Mac around 2005 or 2006. So if you've got some old PowerPC equipment and you're a registered Mac developer, you could...

1. Get copies of Mac OS X and Xcode from that era from developer.apple.com.
2. Load them up on your PowerPC Mac, import the CodeWarrior project, and fix any problems.
3. Get newer and newer versions of Mac OS X and Xcode and bring the code forward, fixing any problems.

However, having done things like this in the past, I would not recommend it unless you absolutely must - for instance, if you have to do regression testing or bug fixes against the original code.

Instead, I would just create a new Xcode project using the command-line utility template, add the source files and forget about the .mcp project, and fix any problems. It will be far less fooling around.